# How to use OpenCL on the Windows XP operating system?

Tags: c, windows-xp, opencl, amd-processor, ati

I have an [ATI Radeon HD 4800](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_4000_Series#Radeon_HD_4800) display card. I want to use [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) on it in Windows XP operating system, but the OpenCL's SDK only work correctly when I install the drivers, which are in version is 11.5.

If the drivers version is higher than 11.5, the OpenCL's SDK installer will give me a notice that "The display driver installed on this system does not have OpenCL support for AMD GPUs". If I want to still use OpenCL on the Windows XP operating system for my GPUs with latest version drivers, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the support for HD 4800 (beta OpenCL) on the latest drivers has fallen. The Java-jocl version does not work either for HD 4870 for latest dirvers. But there isn't a problem for the HD 5800 series.

Similar lack of support can be seen for Intel's HD 3000 series (no problem for HD 4000 series) for the latest drivers.

Comment: thanks for your reply.But When I installs amd sdk 2.3 on the system which has a ATI HD6700 display card, the notice that "the display driver installed on this system dose not have opencl support for AMD GPUs" also can produce.

Comment: Sources say thats 1.1 capable but non-clean driver install can break it too.